# how to incease size of tickmark animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, sass

I am trying to add a animated tickmark to my site but i want to resize this [tickmark](https://codepen.io/haniotis/pen/KwvYLO) to 3-4 times as of now.

CSS:

```
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
    <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
    <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>
</svg>
```

i am trying trying to increase its size but am able to increase size of outer circle but not able to increase size of tick mark. pLease sugest

Comment: stroke-width: 6; perhaps. Depends what you mean by resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the css as below.

Compare items to understand what has been changed.

```
// Colors
$green: #7ac142;
$white: #fff;

// Misc
$curve: cubic-bezier(0.650, 0.000, 0.450, 1.000);

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 156px;
  height: 156px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: $white;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px $green;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .9s ease-in-out 1s both;
}

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 1;
  stroke: $green;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke .6s $curve forwards;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke .3s $curve .8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(0.1, 0.1, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 78px $green;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the path for the "tic" has only lowercase commands after the `M` is easy to move. I've changed the path to: `d="M-11.9 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"` where `14.1 - 26 = -11.9` Now I can transform the `tic` using scale. I'm using `transform="scale(1.5)...` but you can use the scale you need. After scaling I'm translating the "tic" in the center with `translate(26,0)`

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
    <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>
    <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M-11.9 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" transform="scale(1.5) translate(26,0)"/>
</svg>
```